# What is the purpose of libSDL2main.a?

Tags: c++, c, linker, sdl, sdl-2

Some sources say to have `-lSDL2main.a` as one of the files to link against while building SDL2 programs but some don't. The program works fine in either cases. What is it for?

Comment: Which OS are you working on? I assume it is linux.

Comment: @user2023370 Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its purpose is to make entry point the same on all platforms - `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, with UTF8-encoded arguments. While it is so on e.g. linux (where SDLmain doesn't exist or empty), other target systems may follow different scheme.

For example, windows programs may have different entry points - `main`, `WinMain`, `wmain`. With SDLmain, you don't need to handle it differently - just use `main` like on other systems (renamed by SDL to `SDL_main`).

Basically on your code, it only boils down to this line in `SDL_main.h` header (included automatically if you inclue `SDL.h`):

```
#define main    SDL_main
```

(only on systems that have implementation for SDLmain). It renames your `main` to `SDL_main` and injects system-specific entry point (implemented in `SDL2main` library), which converts arguments, does some platform-specific initialisation, and calls your `SDL_main`.

Whether that is a good thing is debatable; this functionality could be disabled with `#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before including `SDL.h`. In that case, you define your own platform-specific entry point, do all required initialisation, but SDL asks you to call `SDL_SetMainReady` before calling any other SDL stuff.

So, to answer your question why sometimes it is used and othertimes it doesn't - it is so because in some cases when you already have "standard" `main` it does nothing.